# how to change src without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was looking for answer on stackoverflow but didn't found it. i'm creating a color switcher

[image]

i have a default path `<script src="js/theme/theme-default.js"></script>` which is working fine on my website

i also created color switcher code

My HTML

```
 <a href="#" data-style="theme-blue" title="blue: #3498DB" style="background: #3498DB">
        </a>
```

My JS

```
 $('.color-changer a').on('click', function(){
        var style = $(this).attr('data-style');
        $('#themeJS').attr('src', 'js/theme/' + style + '.js');
        return false;
    })
```

lets assume if i click on the first color, the path would be changed
 to 
`<script src="js/theme/theme-blue.js"></script>`

it's changing the path if i inspect but it's not giving me the effects which i want from `theme-blue.js`

the js files `theme-default.js` and `theme-blue.js`

( theme-default.js )

```
   $('body').css({
    'background-color':'#eee'
   });
```

( theme-blue.js )

```
     $('body').css({
    'background-color':'#3498db'
   });
```

i want to fix this thing with JS

Comment: You would have to first undo all the changes that the original did before loading the new. and, instead of changing the src, just append a new script element and delete the old.

Comment: Why can't you just change the style you want with js instead of loading another js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel -

As far as I know, you cannot replace runtime javascript by changing the src attribute. But what you are trying to do can be done much easier with CSS. Change the data-style to the color you want to see and use this script instead. See the example below:

```
$('.color-changer a').on('click', function(){
    var style = $(this).attr('data-style');
        $('body').css('background-color', style);
    })
```